# Configure htaccess for url rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need help for my url's rewriting. I want to organize my url's precisely by taking account of the current organization of my current tree:

```
-! /www

.htaccess,
index.php, ...

--! **/views**, /assets

pageA.php, pageB.php, pageC.php

---! **/pageA**, /pageB, /pageC, /errors (404.php, 500.php...)

pageA1.php, **pageA2.php**, pageA3.php
```

---

/!\ I use specific names for each pages, the prefixes and numbers are just for examples and for a better comprehension about connexions between files and folders. In reality I use pages names like: "contact-us.php", "our-product.php" ...

(1) When I going to pageA.php I would like this url path: **www.mywebsite.fr/pageA**

(2) When I going to pageA2.php, I would like: **www.mywebsite.fr/pageA/pageA2**

(3) I don't want extension files (.php, .html)

Actually, I can't go into the path (2) cause I have a 404 page.

I created folders with the same name as a specific php pages it's just for my own organization, but it can be a bad way (for SEO or anything else...) in fact, I don't know...

My rewrite module (in .htaccess of www) is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # Retirer les extensions des pages et les rendres accessibles en lecture
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

    # Suppression d'un sous répertoire
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/views/$1.php -f 
    RewriteRule (.*) /views/$1.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please change your comments to English or remove them when posting on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is just off the top of my head, but it should work:

```
RewriteRule ^page([A-Z]{1})([1-9]?).php$ http://www.mywebsite.fr/page$1$2
RewriteRule ^page([A-Z]{1})([1-9]{1})$ http://www.mywebsite.fr/page$1/page$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

The first Rewrite directive checks for a filename match starting with

*page*

and ending (prior to the filename extension, .php) with

- *a single letter (from A to Z)*; and
- (optionally) *a single number (from 1 to 9)*

If it does, it captures both the letter (and the optional number) and rewrites the URI without the .php file extension at the end.

For those URIs which do include the optional number, the second Rewrite directive captures both the letter and the number separately from each other.

It then builds the redirect according to the correct folder structure, deploying both the captured letter and the captured number.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to reflect something more closely approximating the situation that you need to fix and I'll put my thinking hat on and have another go. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I forgot to specify that the pages haven't the same prefix. I used prefix "pageA", "pageB" ... for example. In reality it is more : "our-team.php", "products.php", "contact-us.php" without numbers...  And the pages : pageA1 , pageA2 ... has different names too ...
In this case I think your example can't apply for my problem ^^

Comment: thank's u @Rounin if you need a picture to illustrate my folder /views, request me.